# How to test simple Ruby class in Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I have a Rails 4 application to which I am adding a simple class as a wrapper around an external API I am calling. The class does not inherit from anything and looks something like:

```
class MyFacade
  def self.foo
    WebService::foo
  end

  def self.bar
    WebService::bar
  end
end
```

I have placed the file into app/classes where it gets autoloaded. This is working fine. The question is, how and where do you write tests for a class like this with only class methods?

Comment: blowmage and Mike Manfrin both gave answers that were helpful. Wish I could mark them both as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create the file `test/models/my_facade_test.rb` and test it there. This is still part of your domain, even if it doesn't inherit from ActiveRecord. Not every domain model needs to be backed by a database table.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly the same way you'd test an ActiveRecord model.

Your tests would look something like:

```
expect(MyFacade.foo).to be_kind_of(WebService::foo)
```

etc.